# Input not clickable when added to Notion through a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, notion

I am building a chrome extension where I add a time tracker and that time tracker has some input fields, the input fields are injected at the top of each page, for some reason those input fields aren't writable at all. I noticed that there is a div that disappears when I click and re-appears again (Not added by me, it's added by Notion)

`<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 0px; flex-grow: 0; z-index: 109; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; pointer-events: auto;"><div style="cursor: col-resize; height: 100%; width: 12px; margin-left: -6px;"></div></div>`

I tried the following and nothing worked so far,

1. adding a high z-index to my element.
2. changing pointer-events.
3. manipulating the div that appears/disappears and changing it's pointer-events to none.
4. stopping click propagation.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try to add the elements created by your extension as [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_shadow_DOM), this way, the CSS of the webpage won't affect them. Here is an example: `someDiv.attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).append(inputElement)`